# dompdf not loading data vo view Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to convert html page to pdf using dompdf wrapper in laravel. If I show the html page, the informations from database are displayed on the page, but when I try to convert that to pdf I have only empty div tags without values from the database.

This is my code for converting pdf:

```
public function viewUserOrderDetails($id){
        $user = User::find($id);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('userOrderDetails',['user' => $user]);
        return $pdf->stream("index.pdf");
    }
```

and the route function:

```
    Route::post('/userOrderDetails/{id}',[
   'uses' => 'showAllOrders@viewUserOrderDetails',
   'as' => 'orderdetail',
]);
```

View sample code:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="col-lg-12 form-group margin50">
      <label class="col-lg-2"  for="Name">User</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="" class="form-control name" value="{{ $user->name }}" readonly>
          {{ csrf_field() }}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" col-lg-12 form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-2" for="ProductType">Orders</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         @foreach($user->orders as $order)
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control name" value="{{ $order->order_name }}" readonly>
         @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
      <label class="col-lg-2" for="Manufacturer">Price</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        @foreach($user->orders as $order)
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control name" value="{{ $order->cena }}" readonly>
         @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
    </form>
```

Also if i try to change `$pdf = PDF::loadView('userOrderDetails',['user' => $user]);` to this 
`$pdf = PDF::loadView('userOrderDetails',compact('user'));` it gives me `user not found error`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the error message exactly?

Comment: I don't have errors, the pdf page is loading perfectly but it gives me empty div tags, it doesnt loading data from the database

Comment: Try the key as a variable like $name instead of $user->name.